# hadoop - How can I intervene in case of task failure?

Tags: hadoop

I have a job that parses many urls.
if each task processes a single url, then the task will fail if the parsing of a single url throws an exception.
in the regular hadoop behaivour, this task will be reattempted 3 times, and after that the job will fail.
can I somehow intervene in case of task failure and write my own code that will disregard the task?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you catch the exception?

Anyway, you can set [maxMapTaskFailuresPercent](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setMaxMapTaskFailuresPercent%28int%29) and [maxReduceTaskFailuresPercent](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setMaxReduceTaskFailuresPercent%28int%29) suitably.

Comment: its java heap space excpetion. I cant catch it.
and these params wont give me what I need. I talking about tasks that will ALWAYS fail, and thus I want to "exclude" them when I see that they filed X times.